# Finding the WEEK number for 1st January - Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am calculating the first week of every month for past 12 months from current date. The query logic that I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),interval  10 month), MONTH)) AS YYMMDD,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval  10 month), MONTH)) AS YYMM,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%W', DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval  10 month), MONTH)) AS YYWW
```

OUTPUT:

| Row | YYMMDD | YYMM | YYWW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210101 | 202101 | 202100 |

The `YYWW` format returns the week as `00` and is causing my logic to fail. Is there anyway to handle this? My logic is going to be running 12 months calculation to find first week of every month.

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic level, you can accomplish it with something like this:

```
with calendar as (
    select date, extract(day from date) as day_of_month 
    from unnest(generate_date_array('2021-01-01',current_date(), interval 1 day)) date
)
select
    date,
    extract(month from date) as month_of_year,
    case
        when day_of_month < 8  then 1
        when day_of_month < 15 then 2
        when day_of_month < 22 then 3
        when day_of_month < 29 then 4
        else 5
    end as week_of_month
from calendar
order by date
```

This approach is very simplistic, but you gave no criteria for your `week-of-month` definition in the query, so this is a reasonable answer.  There is potential for a ton of variation in how you define `week-of-month`. The logic for `week-of-year` is built in to BQ, and provides options to handle items such as the starting day of the week, carryover at the end/beginning of consecutive years, etc.  There is no corresponding `week-of-month` logic out of the box, so any "easy" built-in function like `FORMAT_DATE()` is unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks rtenha for response. I am trying to find the first week number of every month for past 12 months .  When I built the query with below logic, I get the first week no for every month except Jan-21. The first week of Jan-21 is returned as 2100 instead of 2101.  

SELECT 
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%W', DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval  10 month), MONTH)) AS YYWW,
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%W', DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval  09 month), MONTH)) AS YYWW,


Row YYWW YYWW_1 YYWW_2 YYWW_3 YYWW_4 YYWW_5 YYWW_6 
1 202100 202105 202109 202113 202117 202122 202126

Comment: I perhaps misunderstood your initial question, because looking for `202101`, `202105`, `202109`, `etc` was not clear in your original question.  Regardless, because Jan 01, 2021 is a Friday, and BQ natively starts weeks on a Monday, it is treating the 1st thru the 3rd (F-S-Su) as the "0th" week.  This is BQ internal logic, and no manipulation with built-in date functions is likely to solve this problem for you.  You will need to create custom logic.  The easiest method might be to use an `IF` statement to force `01` when `00` is returned from the `FORMAT_DATE()` function.